# How to reduce more `SELECT` queries which are already reduced by "prefetch_related()" to iterate 3 or more models?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-prefetch-related

I have `Country`, `State` and `City` models which are chained by foreign keys as shown below:

```py
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then, I iterate `Country` and `State` models with [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) as shown below:

```py
for country_obj in Country.objects.prefetch_related("state_set").all():
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.all():
        print(country_obj, state_obj)
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below. *I use PostgreSQL and these below are the query logs of PostgreSQL and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries#answer-75031321) explaining how to enable and disable the query logs on PostgreSQL:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Country`, `State` and `City` models with prefetch_related() as shown below:

```py
for country_obj in Country.objects.prefetch_related("state_set__city_set").all():
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.all():
        for city_obj in state_obj.city_set.all():
            print(country_obj, state_obj, city_obj)
```

Then, 3 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Now, how can I reduce 3 `SELECT` queries to 2 `SELECT` queries or less for the example just above iterating `Country`, `State` and `City` models with `prefetch_related()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using nested prefetch_related.

```
prefetch_city_qs = City.objects.all()
prefetched_city = Prefetch('state_set', to_attr='prefetched_city_set',
                            query_set=prefetch_city_qs)

join_tables_2 = [prefetched_city]
prefetch_state_qs = State.objects.prefetch_related(*join_tables_2).all()
prefetched_state = Prefetch('state_set', to_attr='prefetched_state_set',
                            query_set=prefetch_state_qs)

join_tables_1 = [prefetched_state]

countries = Country.objects.prefetch_related(*join_tables).all()
```

then when you iterate, you should be access the same using loops.
like

```
for country in countries:
   for state in country.prefetched_state_set:
       for city in state.prefetched_city_set:
           print(city, state, country)
```

Apologies for language and format as its my first response in stackoverflow