# Taking incremental pg_dump since last restore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

We are developing a large application and all our tests are based on a reference Test DB. This test DB is initially loaded by executing different scripts and you can add your own script to add more data.

I want to ease the following flow

- I have loaded the test DB
- I do some data modifications to the DB indirectly (e.g by just using the application)
- **I can generate a SQL script of the data modification**

I am looking for the most efficient way to do it. So far my best solution is:

1. I load the test DB under an other name
2. I take a `pg_dump` in sql format of the vanilla test DB and the modified one
3. I do a diff of both `pg_dump` output

This not really great because:

- Loading test DB takes time and space
- Test DB has some time information which will pollute the diff (e.g tables with `created_date` column)

Any better solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve? What are you going to do with the diff?

Comment: It is an interesting approach that I didn't think about. Log statement could be indeed a starting point to generate a diff but also I want the result SQL to be somewhat compact.
For example if a row is inserted and then deleted, I don't really want it.
It doesn't feel like a silver bullet but it sure is an interesting angle.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The diff is used to enrich the test DB, so we can write tests against newly created data. 
The script that creates the test DB takes 3 input: the schema generated from the source code of the app, some real world data from a live environment and some custom SQL script provided by the developers.